# Is it worth spending more to buy the Canon 500D vs the Canon 450D?

Tags: canon, dslr, canon-450d, canon-500d

I would like to get into photography but I'd like to gather more information about the topic first. I'm thinking about buying a starter D-SLR camera, and am leaning heavily towards a Canon (most of my friends are using Canon).

Budget is important for me, so **do think is it worth it to spend more money to a buy the Canon 500D instead of the Canon 450D?** I don't think I will use video feature...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 450D is plenty camera for anyone taking up photography. I would spend the money saved on better lenses.

Answer (score 12):

As someone who owns a 450D myself, and who has a friend who owns a 500D, I would say the 500D is worth it. Functionally, there are few differences. The 450D has a 12.2mp sensor, while the 500D has a 15.1mp sensor. Not a huge difference, but enough to make a difference. The 500D supports two stops higher ISO (6400 instead of 1600...12800 is digitally enhanced, which you can do in post processing yourself). The higher ISO is a significant feature, as there are times when the 450D just can't get the shot, even with a fast lens. Another significant update to the 500D is HD video capability. That may or may not be a factor for you, depending on whether you are interested in video or not.

One of the more significant features of the 500D over the 450D is the LCD view screen. The 450D has a 230,000 dot 3" screen, which is actually fairly low resolution by todays standards, and is rather dim at times. It can be difficult to read during the day when you are out and about. The 500D has a 920,000 dot screen, which is four times as high a resolution, and considerably brighter. Using the 500D in brighter conditions is a LOT nicer than using the 450D. The higher resolution also makes it a lot easier to review your pictures in-camera, as you can see a much finer level of detail. Trying to review pictures in the 450D can be frustrating at times, as you can really never tell if your sharpness and focus is acceptable until you view your images on a computer.

All that said, the 550D is again another improvement on all of these features again, and brings some other new things into the game. The 550D has a much improved sensor with the same noise performance as the 7D. Additionally, the 550D brings full color metering to the Rebel line, which is a significant improvement over the previous metering sensors used in the 450D and 500D. The 550D also uses the Digic 4 image processor, so it is capable of outputting 14-bit RAW images, allowing for greater dynamic range and finer tonal gradations than the previous Rebels.

The price difference between a 500D and 550D is about $100, and I would say that the 550D is DEFINITELY worth it. If I had to offer up a recommendation out of all three, it would be the 550D hands down. The 500D does offer some useful improvements over the 450D, however 14-bit images, full color metering, and 50% more megapixels than the 450D make the 550D hard to beat for only $100 more.

Comment: "Trying to review pictures in the 450D can be frustrating at times, as you can really never tell if your sharpness and focus is acceptable until you view your images on a computer." is a very good point. I will buy my camera from Turkey and price difference is like 450D (0), 500D(+200$) and 550D(+450$), I'm really confused. Does "review pictures" on LCD make that much difference?

Comment: I'm with jrista with this one. If you can afford it, go for the 550D. It's not only the LCD size...

Comment: @metdos: Reviewing images on the LCD is not the only difference that matters. Having used the 450D for almost two years myself, I can tell you that using live view or reviewing pictures is only useful to make sure you composed right...reviewing focus and sharpness is difficult at best, pointless at worst. There are MANY more benefits to the 550D that makes it a FAR more worthwhile camera than either of the other two...14-bit RAW and color metering being two primary ones.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the well thought out answer - it helps me with my decision making too.

Comment: For reviewing, what matters is not only the resolution of the screen but also the resolution of the image that you are reviewing. Even if you are shooting RAW only, the camera will automatically embed inside the RAW file a low-resolution JPEG file that you can review in-camera. In the case of 500D, the "low-resolution JPEG" is actually a *full-resolution* JPEG file (which takes approx. 3 megabytes). Hence when you are reviewing and zooming in-camera, you have access to a full-resolution "thumbnail", which is not necessarily the case with other cameras (unless you shoot JPEG or RAW+JPEG).

Comment: According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_500D the 500D also has 14bit RAW, you don't need to get the 550D for that.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't anything 'Normal' which you can do with 500D but can't with 450D. 450D is a very good entry level DSLR. But I'd suggest, if you can, wait a little longer and buy 550D, definitely a bigger bang for your buck.
You can compare 450D and 500D here:
http://snapsort.com/compare/Canon_EOS_450D-vs-Canon_EOS_500D

Answer (score 0):

I have the 500D, and I am a little disappointed with the noise performance. Long exposures (20-30sec) at ISO 100 have a fair amount of visible noise in the dark areas. And I think twice before setting the ISO above 400.

As the 450D is older and has even poorer noise performance, I would recommend stepping up, perhaps even to the 550D, as it should have better noise performance than the 500D